How to fetch user from Firebase Firestore that is distinct of the currently logged in, in Flutter app?
I am using SwipableStack package in Flutter to show images of every user (distinct than currently logged in) and swipe them and go to the next user image to swipe and show their profile images one by one on SwipableStack. But somehow, the image is always the same.
Here is my function for getting random user, it fetches random user from Firestore and then I am using users uid to get image from Storage in format "uid.jpg":
Future<DocumentSnapshot?> getRandomUser2({DocumentSnapshot? lastDoc}) async {
    try {
      final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      final currentUserId = currentUser?.uid;

      if (currentUserId == null || currentUserId.isEmpty) {
        print("Error: Current user ID is null or empty.");
        return null; // Exit early if the user ID is invalid
      }

      Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .where('uid', isNotEqualTo: currentUserId)
          .limit(1); // Fetch one user at a time

      if (lastDoc != null && lastDoc.exists) {
        query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDoc); // Pagination if needed
      }

      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.get();

      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        DocumentSnapshot randomUser = querySnapshot.docs.first;
        setState(() {
          lastFetchedUser = randomUser; // Update pagination reference
        });

        String imageUrl = "";
        List<String> tempUrls = [];

        if (randomUser['uid'] != null && randomUser['uid'].isNotEmpty) {
          Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('user_images')
              .child('${randomUser['uid']}.jpg');

          try {
            imageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
            print('Fetched image URL: $imageUrl'); // Debug print
            tempUrls.add(imageUrl);
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error fetching image URL for user ${randomUser['uid']}: $e');
          }
        } else {
          print('Invalid or missing UID for the user');
        }

        // Overwrite the image URL list and reset currentIndexImage
        setState(() {
          imageUrlList = tempUrls; // Overwrite with new image URL
          currentIndexImage = 0; // Reset to zero
          isLoading = false; // Update loading state
        });

        return randomUser; // Return the fetched user
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching user: $e');
    }

    return null; // Return null if no more users or an error occurred
  }

And UI is like this, but I always get same user in Swipable Stack. The Item coount is always 1 to get one user at the time and I am getting images from Firebase Storage in format "uid.jpg"`
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        if (isLoading) // Show loading indicator if still loading
          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        else if (imageUrlList.isNotEmpty)
          SwipableStack(
            itemCount: 1, // Always show 1 item
            builder: (context, properties) {
              String imageUrl =
                  imageUrlList[currentIndexImage]; // Always use index 0
              print('Displaying image: $imageUrl'); // Debug print

              return ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60.0),
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: 0.95,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: imageUrl,
                    progressIndicatorBuilder:
                        (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                                value: downloadProgress.progress),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            onSwipeCompleted: (index, direction) async {
              setState(() {
                isLoading =
                    true; // Show a loading indicator when fetching next user
              });

              print('Swiped $direction');

              await getRandomUser2(lastDoc: lastFetchedUser);

              setState(() {
                isLoading = false; // Hide loading indicator when done
              });
            },
          )


You're using await storageRef.getDownloadURL() and then add that to tempUrls. But for most URLs this will happen after you call setState, which means the UI won't be updated.
To fix this, call setState whenever you add a new download URL. For example:
String imageUrl = "";
List<String> tempUrls = [];

if (randomUser['uid'] != null && randomUser['uid'].isNotEmpty) {
  Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('user_images')
      .child('${randomUser['uid']}.jpg');

  try {
    imageUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
    print('Fetched image URL: $imageUrl'); // Debug print
    tempUrls.add(imageUrl);

    //  Move this code *inside* the block that as the await call
    // Overwrite the image URL list and reset currentIndexImage
    setState(() {
      imageUrlList = tempUrls; // Overwrite with new image URL
      currentIndexImage = 0; // Reset to zero
      isLoading = false; // Update loading state
    });

  } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching image URL for user ${randomUser['uid']}: $e');
  }
} else {
  print('Invalid or missing UID for the user');
}

This will probably cause some flicker as the URLs come in over time, but should solve the not-showing problem.

Thank you for your comment. I found the solution earlier and that is that I added .orderBy('uid') after where, when I fetch user from Firestore. I need to use .orderBy('uid') in Firestore query because Firestore requires you to specify an orderBy clause when you use pagination methods like startAfterDocument.
